# .Rbuildignore - how to exclude all invisible files?

Tags: r, package

I am trying to exclude all invisible files in all subdirectories from the R package build process:

`R CMD build`

By specifying a regular expression in .Rbuildignore file.

However none of the things I try work - they either do nothing or exclude all the files and the build fails because DESCRIPTION get's excluded.

Things I tried:

```
^\\.
^\.
.*
\.*
^\\.*
```

But none of them work. Is there an expression I can use to exclude all file starting with "." ?

Comment: I would have thought  : `^\.*`  would work ?

Comment: @SymbolixAU with that I am getting `Error in .read_description(ldpath)` and it says `DESCRIPTION does not exist`. Seems like it's removing all of the files?

Comment: Maybe more explicitly `^[^.].*$` ?

Comment: @SymbolixAU thank you for suggestions. But still the same result - DESCRIPTION not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to `.Rbuildignore` (or/and in `.Rinstignore` if needed)

```
^[.].*$
^.*/[.].*$
```

- First line to ignore hidden file(s) in folder
- Second line to ignore hidden file(s) in sub-folder(s)